# How to make Ionic 3 app read existing data from window.localstorage used by Ionic 1 app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

We have Ionic 1 app released in play store. It is using window.localStorage to store user login info. Now we are upgrading to Ionic 3. We don't want our existing users to login again. So, this new Ionic 3 app needs to read data from window.localStorage. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated!

Comment: `localStorage.getItem()` this should work. i haven't done this. but give it a try.

Comment: Not working the way that we expect...Looks like Ionic 1 & Ionic 3 use separate localStorage path. Not sure whether it is because of different Cordova / WebView versions (8.x & 9.x) ? Atleast if we know the path where both versions store localStrage, we can try to read data from there.

Comment: its better to login again. and use secure storage ionic native storage for this purpose.